# Forward/back buttons for answers should indicate start/end

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Would be nice to see start/end indication for the forward/back buttons inside a question. Maybe the pressed image could be the same as disabled (in case there is no more need to go up or in case there are jo more answers available).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be in the next build.  I'll push it out on Monday so I don't start the weekend with a bunch of crash reports.